# Nginx server only shows default page

Tags: nginx

I have a problem with Nginx server as it only shows default page. Virtual host and host file seem to be ok. I don't get where is the problem.

Here is my virtual host configuration:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    listen   [::]:80;
    listen 443 default ssl;
    server_name marketplace_unirgy;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;
    root /var/www/html/marketplace_unirgy/;
    index index.php;
    #location / {
    #       index index.html index.php;
    #       autoindex on;
    #       #If missing pass the URI to Magento's front handler
    #       try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
    #       expires max;
    #}
    #need it to execute php
    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            include fastcgi_params;
            include fastcgi.conf;
    }
    ## Magento uses a common front handler
    location @handler {
            rewrite / /index.php;
    }
}
```

And my host:

```
127.0.0.1 marketplace_unirgy localhost
```

My website is in `/var/www/html/marketplace_unirgy`

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have the default location commented out for some reason. Try enabling it with:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) and [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.

Comment: thank you for helping me there were a problem with field 'patht inside 'core_config_data' in my magento database. If this value is not correctly set your URL get redirected to the value inside this field. It was hidden from me.